# Javascript: How can I use the filter() to filter out specific objects with a certain value?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with accounts, example:

```
    {
      "amount": "822370.71",
      "state": "ME"
    },
    {
      "amount": "968817.53",
      "state": "FL"
    },
    {
      "amount": "587603.26",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "FL"
    }
```

Let's say I want to filter out only the objects with the states of "FL" and "OH", how could I use the filter() to do that? Thanks.

Comment: example here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function filterArray (item) {
    if (item.state === "OH" || item.state === "FL"){
        return item;
    }
}

var resultArray = yourArray.filter(filterArray);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: `return item.state === "OH" || item.state === "FL";` would yield the same result.

Comment: Yes it would yield same result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var array = [{
      "amount": "822370.71",
      "state": "ME"
    },
    {
      "amount": "968817.53",
      "state": "FL"
    },
    {
      "amount": "587603.26",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "FL"
    }];
    
    var filterArray = array.filter(function(item){
      return item.state === 'FL' || item.state === 'OH';
    });
    
    console.log(filterArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array.filter(callback)` which takes a function with one argument and return the value that meets the condition you want :

```
var testArray = [ {
      "amount": "822370.71",
      "state": "ME"
    },
    {
      "amount": "968817.53",
      "state": "FL"
    },
    {
      "amount": "587603.26",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "OH"
    },
    {
      "amount": "657617.83",
      "state": "FL"
    }];
  var filtered = testArray.filter(isStateFLorOH);
```

and the fucntion callback should be like this :

```
function isStateFLorOH(value){

if(value.state == "FL" || value.satate == "OH")
return value;
}
```